# Using VBScript to access C++ COM module

Tags: c++, vbscript, com

First time question asker - I have searched through the site for questions related to VBSCRIPT, C++, and COM.  I have found a couple of threads that I do believe speak to my core question but I was not able to walk away with an absolute.

I have been tasked with writing an automation script for a trucking company that uses PCMIler (which is arguably the most pervasive commercial trip routing tool in the market).  The product comes with a tool called PCMiler Connect. PCmiler connect offers various API's to query the database.  One of those is COM.

PCMiler is written in C++.  I'm trying to accomplish this with VBScript.

The problem I'm having is trying to execute a method that requires 1 argument to be passed by reference.  The method takes 4 arguments.  It uses 3 of them to calculate the distance in miles from 2 points.  The 4th argument is the one passed by reference and the retval is the 'time' in minutes.

```
Set server = CreateObject("PCMServer.PCMServer")
region = Server.DefaultRegion

Dim dist  'dist is short for Distance
Dim minutes
Dim time
'First Example  use standard CalcDistance  //THIS FUNCTION WORKS JUST FINE.
dist = server.CalcDistance("63139","62025")  'the passed parameters are Zip Codes
Wscript.Echo "CalcDistance: " & (dist / 10)   'Echo the distance in miles

//THIS EXAMPLE DOES NOT WORK!!!!
'Third Example  use CalcDistance3 with a Route Type of 'Practical' (which is the 3rd argument).      Pass variable 'minutes' as the return variable.
'Third Example - version 1.  Passing the variable 'minutes' by itself - no character to indicate it is being passed by reference.
dist = server.CalcDistance3("63139","37217",1,cLng(time))
```

I have read in some threads that C++ must return the retval as Variant.  This function returns a Long Integer.  I can't change this.  When I read the log file for PCMiler connect I can see where the retval is being calculated and logged - but VBScript is not picking it up, or it is not being returned correctly?

Ultimately - I'd like to ask someone to tell me If I'm out of look for using VBScript due to the fact I can't alter the C++ method - or if I can find a way to get the value - please help.  If not - can someone tell me a better option for what I need to do?

1. While I have successfully used VBA in Access - this needs to be an automated script running every 30 minutes.  I understand Access is not something that can be run reliably as an automated service.
2. C#?
3. VB?

Thank you.

Comment: Is VBScript throwing an error? Also, are you concerned about the 4th param or is the return value (`dist`) the only thing you need?

Comment: VBScript is not throwing an error (as long as I wrap the 4th argument in the cLng() function).  Correct - I am concerned about the 4th parameter.  'dist' holds the value of the distance.  'Distance' is the value returned to 'dist'.  The method is supposed to assign the time (in minutes) to the 4th argument, which is supposed to be passed by reference.  After the method completes - when I echo out the value of 'time' - it displays 0.  The answer should be 440 (based on the values in the calcDistance3 method.

Comment: Not all COM interface can be accessed by VBScript. To simplify, VBScript needs a Automation-compatible interface. Is this PCMServer thing automation compatible? (or where is the doc for this interface?)

Comment: There is various PDF on http://www.pcmiler.com/ which I found using google ( https://www.google.fr/search?q=PCMIler+automation+COM+Server ) They contain useful infos, as "chapter 5 Using PC*MILER|Connect
From Visual Basic" Did you read that?

Comment: Try to get the Visual Basic declaration file PCMSRV32.TXT